# GET parameters are not recognized

Tags: php

I have two URLs.

This one works: `equipo.php?equipo=sk+gaming&page=2&ipp=24`
This one does not: `equipo/sk+gaming.html?page=2&ipp=24`

`equipo/sk+gaming.html` does the same thing as `equipo.php?equipo=sk+gaming`, as it should.

My problem is that when using `equipo/sk+gaming.html?page=2&ipp=24`, the `page` parameter isn't there.

Why am I not getting the `page` parameter and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Apache's `mod_rewrite`, the `RewriteRule` probably doesn't have the `QSA` flag.

Comment: my rewrite it's like this
Rewriterule ^equipo/(.*?).html$ equipo.php?equipo=$1 [L]

Comment: @Zuker: You have the `L` flag there. You need the `QSA` flag as well, as I noted in my question.